# Check if a numpy array contains numerical data

Tags: python, numpy

This function serves me as a testing-utility to check if the result is really numeric and sometimes as input-validation if there are a lot of operations before I would find out (with an Exception) if it's not-numerical.

But I feel like the `.dtype.kind in ...` is too complex. I've written this function a while back and tried using some better approach but I couldn't find any solution that works for python 2.7 and 3.x and different numpy version 1.7+.

The code:

```
import numpy as np

def is_numeric_array(array):
    """Checks if the dtype of the array is numeric.

    Booleans, unsigned integer, signed integer, floats and complex are
    considered numeric. 

    Parameters
    ----------
    array : `numpy.ndarray`-like
        The array to check.

    Returns
    -------
    is_numeric : `bool`
        True if it is a recognized numerical and False if object or
        string.
    """
    numerical_dtype_kinds = {'b', # boolean
                             'u', # unsigned integer
                             'i', # signed integer
                             'f', # floats
                             'c'} # complex
    try:
        return array.dtype.kind in numerical_dtype_kinds
    except AttributeError:
        # in case it's not a numpy array it will probably have no dtype.
        return np.asarray(array).dtype.kind in numerical_dtype_kinds
```

and I have the following tests:

```
def test_not_array():
    assert is_numeric_array(1)
    assert is_numeric_array(1.)
    assert is_numeric_array(1+1j)
    assert not is_numeric_array('a')
    assert not is_numeric_array(None)
    assert is_numeric_array([1, 2, 3])


def test_array():
    assert is_numeric_array(np.array(1))
    assert is_numeric_array(np.array(1.))
    assert is_numeric_array(np.array(1+1j))
    assert is_numeric_array(np.array([1]))
    assert is_numeric_array(np.array([1.]))
    assert is_numeric_array(np.array([1+1j]))
    assert not is_numeric_array(np.array('a'))
    assert not is_numeric_array(np.array(['a']))

test_not_array()
test_array()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### 1. Question

You write, "I feel like the `.dtype.kind in ...` is too complex". You're probably right about that: I've never needed anything like this in NumPy code. Normally I know what the datatypes are, or I rely on the caller setting them up correctly. But I don't think I can help unless you can explain what you are using this for. Why do you need to know whether an array is numeric or not?

*Update:* you say in comments that you are trying validate data read in from files. For this use case, consider using [`np.genfromtxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html#numpy.genfromtxt), passing `loose=False`. For example:

```
>>> from io import BytesIO
>>> np.genfromtxt(BytesIO(b'1,2,x,3'), dtype=float, delimiter=',', loose=False)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "numpy/lib/_iotools.py", line 688, in _strict_call
    new_value = self.func(value)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: b'x'
```

#### 2. Review

1. You've written a docstring! That's excellent.
2. But I think the docstring could be clearer about what happens when `array` is not a NumPy array. I would write something like, "Determine whether the argument has a numeric datatype, when converted to a NumPy array."
3. The docstring says, "False if object or string" but those are not the only non-numeric kinds (there's also unicode and void), so I would write something like, "True if the array has a numeric datatype, False if not."
4. `np.asarray` is cheap if the argument is already an array: "No copy is performed if the input is already an ndarray" so you might as well call it in all cases, and avoid the `try: ... except:` and the duplicated code.
5. The set `numerical_dtype_kinds` is always the same, and so it ought to be a global variable.
6. The test cases would be more convenient to run if you used the features in the [`unittest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html) module.
7. There's a lot of repetition in the test cases. Since all the tests are of the form `assert is_numeric_array(x)` or `assert not is_numeric_array(x)`, it would make sense to put the test cases in a couple of lists, and iterate over them. There's duplication between `test_not_array` and `test_array` that could easily be removed.
8. There are no test cases checking that Booleans are numeric, or that objects are not.

#### 3. Revised code

```
import numpy as np

# Boolean, unsigned integer, signed integer, float, complex.
_NUMERIC_KINDS = set('buifc')

def is_numeric(array):
    """Determine whether the argument has a numeric datatype, when
    converted to a NumPy array.

    Booleans, unsigned integers, signed integers, floats and complex
    numbers are the kinds of numeric datatype.

    Parameters
    ----------
    array : array-like
        The array to check.

    Returns
    -------
    is_numeric : `bool`
        True if the array has a numeric datatype, False if not.

    """
    return np.asarray(array).dtype.kind in _NUMERIC_KINDS


from unittest import TestCase

class TestIsNumeric(TestCase):
    NUMERIC = [True, 1, -1, 1.0, 1+1j]
    NOT_NUMERIC = [object(), 'string', u'unicode', None]

    def test_is_numeric(self):
        for x in self.NUMERIC:
            for y in (x, [x], [x] * 2):
                for z in (y, np.array(y)):
                    self.assertTrue(is_numeric(z))
        for x in self.NOT_NUMERIC:
            for y in (x, [x], [x] * 2):
                for z in (y, np.array(y)):
                    self.assertFalse(is_numeric(z))
        for kind, dtypes in np.sctypes.items():
            if kind != 'others':
                for dtype in dtypes:
                    self.assertTrue(is_numeric(np.array([0], dtype=dtype)))
```

Comment: I'm using `pytest` to run the tests so I'll probably don't switch to `unittest`. One use-case is in a function that validates datasets from external sources. It checks if they all have the right shape, meta-information and also if they are all numerical. In case of big sets, I have several 100s of files and this validation can reject them before I try to process them. I had some datasets once where invalid points (unfortunatly on average only 1 file in 100 contained such  an invalid point) were marked with strings. Cost me a lot of time then and I've created this function.

Comment: I have to check this evening if the documentation renders and testcases run in my environment but overall this looks amazing. Thank you!

Comment: (1) If you're committed to particular documentation and test frameworks, then obviously stick to them (you didn't mention them in the post, so I couldn't take them into account in my answer). (2) See the update in §1.

Comment: (1) Sorry I hadn't mentioned them, but that didn't mean I won't try your suggestions (converted for my framework): I'll parametrizing the tests and improving the docstrings as suggested. (2) That will require seriously rewriting other parts of the code. I appreciate the suggestion but I won't use it (anytime soon) :-)